# How many lags should be considered when testing for serial correlation in the error terms?

Tags: autocorrelation, lags

In a time-series OLS regression of daily stock returns on a set of explanatory variables I want to test whether the error terms are auto-correlated before I decide to use Newey-West standard errors (heteroskedasticity is present).

Using the Breusch-Godfrey test, I have to specify a number of lags that shall be considered in the test for serial correlation.

- Is there any intuition (maybe an economic one?) for considering more than first order serial correlation?
- If yes, is there any theory or empirical finding that can be used to choose a reasonable lag length up to which I have to check?

Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: Use back ticks \` for code, do not italicize. Also, related question: ["Breusch-Godfrey Test and the length of the lag, p"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178813/breusch-godfrey-test-and-the-length-of-the-lag-p?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I edited the formatting. I also noticed the question (and upvoted it) but as it is quite old and still unanswered I thought I'd provide some additional information on my specific setting in the hope someone could help out here.

Comment: Since you are using stock returns, I dont see why you want to include more than say, 10 lags... In any case, the test is not really that general, I would use NeweyWest standard errors in any case just to be sure. The gain of doing so is significant (i.e. robust standard errors), there is no real cost.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Repmat! I have a variety of regressions (about 20) that use the same set of controls and only differ in their explanatory variable. I wanted to check each regression for heteroskedasticity and serial correlation. In case only the former is present I wanted to use White standard errors, if both is present Newey-West. Would you consider this as too cumbersome? And is there really no cost in doing so? Because there are some recognized papers that "only" use White, so I wonder how they decided to not use Newey-West.

Comment: In general, I can't picture any modern paper that would accept you not using robust standard errors - especially once you go into time series (unless you are doing some very specific simulation or similar). Both HC and HAC estimator are only valid asymptotically, I suppose that the HC estimator is a bit more efficient (since you only have one level of uncertainty) but from a practional point of view it should not matter (which is what I meant to imply)

Comment: Alright, the more I think about it I feel using Newey throughout my set will be a good idea. I just didn't want to correct for something that is not really there and, as I am lacking some experience, didn't know that this would be anyways justifiable. Thanks for your time!

Comment: The related question mentioned by @RichardHardy has now been answered: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/178813/182174